# Separate only at first instance with multiple delimiters using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have some strings which are in a format

```
lorem ipsum, dolor sit - amet, consectetur : adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc
```

I want it to get split at the first instance of each separator, to return

```
['lorem ipsum',
'dolor sit', 
'amet, consectetur', 
'adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc']
```

Right now my output is

```
['lorem ipsum',
'dolor sit',
'amet',
'consectetur ',
'adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc']
```

Right now I'm using `re.split(', | - |: ', txt)` but it separates at all the instances in the string. Any suggestions on how I can achieve the required output?

**Edit:**

I realised my question isn't clear, so for an example, if the string is

```
"abc: def: ijk, lmno: pqr - stu, wx"
```

the output should be

```
["abc",
"def: ijk",
"lmno: pqr",
"stu, wxy"]
```

and not

```
["abc",
"def",
"ijk",
"lmno",
"pqr",
"stu",
"wxy"]
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @OrY the desired output is in the question.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Run his regex, this is the output of that regex. if this is his desired output than he has no problem

Comment: @OrY my bad, added an extra space there by mistake, fixed it now

Comment: This seems like a bit of an isolated edge case. It would be easier to write in some logic to your program and do it with multiple steps rather than trying one complicated regex. Then you could wrap that in a function.

Comment: @beroe yeah I'm doing that with a normal split function rn, but something like a regex expression looked clean and elegant

Comment: @Eagle Does the string have to contain all separators at least once?

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes it does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all separators have to be present at least once, instead of using split you could use 4 capturing groups with a backreference matching 1 of the 3 options except what is already matched.

```
^(.*?)(, | - |: )(.*?)(?!\2)(, | - |: )(.*?)(?!\2|\4)(, | - |: )(.*)
```

The pattern will match

- `^` Start of string
- `(.*?)` Group **1**, match as least as possible
- `(, | - |: )` Group **2**, match any of the listed
- `(.*?)` Group **3**, match as least as possible
- `(?!\2)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not what is matched in group 2 (pick one of 2 valid options)
- `(, | - |: )` Group **4**, match any of the listed
- `(.*?)` Group **5**, match as least as possible
- `(?!\2|\4)` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not what is matched in group 2 or group 4 (Pick the only valid option left)
- `(, | - |: )` Group **6**, match any of the listed
- `(.*)` Group **7**, match any char as much as possible

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AsyDwB/1)

For example

```
import re

regex = r"^(.*?)(, | - |: )(.*?)(?!\2)(, | - |: )(.*?)(?!\2|\4)(, | - |: )(.*)"

test_str = ("lorem ipsum, dolor sit - amet , consectetur : adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc\n\n"
    "abc: def: ijk, lmno: pqr - stu, wx\n\n")

matches = re.search(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

if matches:
    print(matches.group(1))
    print(matches.group(3))
    print(matches.group(5))
    print(matches.group(7))
```

Output

```
lorem ipsum
dolor sit
amet , consectetur 
adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc
```

See Python [demo1](https://ideone.com/SV7maM) and [demo2](https://ideone.com/rsKGl4)

Comment: That was because of a bad example I chose, but say the string is something like `abc: def: ijk, lmno: pqr - stu, wxy`, the output should be separated by the first instances of all these separators, and should return `["abc", "def: ijk" "lmno: pqr", "stu, wxy"]`

I'll edit the question to reflect the same

Comment: @Eagle So you first want to split on `, ` Then on ` - ` and then on  `: `  ?

Comment: More like separate at three places only

#1 Where `,` appears for the first time
#2 Where `: ` appears for the first time
#3 Where ` - ` appears for the first time

Comment: @Eagle I have changed the answer using capturing groups.

Answer (score 2):

Just food for thought, not sure if it's a valued answer but maybe if you can use `regex` instead of `re` module to utilize the capability of a negative lookbehind with a non-fixed width. For example:

```
\s*([,:-])(?<!\1.*\1)\s*
```

In Python:

```
import regex as re
string1 = "abc: def: ijk, lmno: pqr - stu, wx"
lst1 = re.sub(r'\s*([,:-])(?<!\1.*\1)\s*', '|' , string1).split('|')
print(lst1)
```

Result:

```
['abc', 'def: ijk', 'lmno: pqr', 'stu, wx']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked, but how could I split it from ` - ` instead of `-` and by `: ` instead of `:`?
As in, with spaces before and after `-` and a space after `:`

Comment: Not sure if I understand you well enough. Maybe use + instead of *?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a small class that counts the replacements:

```
import re

text = "lorem ipsum, dolor sit - amet, consectetur : adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc"
# text = "abc: def: ijk, lmno: pqr - stu, wx"
rx = re.compile(r'[-,:]')


class Replacer:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        for key in args:
            setattr(self, key, 0)
        self.needle = kwargs.get("needle")

    def __call__(self, match):
        key = match.group(0)
        setattr(self, key, getattr(self, key, 0) + 1)
        cnt = getattr(self, key, 0)
        return self.needle if cnt == 1 else key


rpl = Replacer("-", ",", ":", needle="#@#")

result = [item.strip() for item in re.split("#@#", rx.sub(rpl, text))]
print(result)
```

Which yields

```
['lorem ipsum', 'dolor sit', 'amet, consectetur', 'adipiscing elit. Praesent vitae orc']
```